# JQuery loads after F5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have used the following script in my asp.net project. All is working fine but after releasing my prject to IIS, some users are complaining about rendering issues. If they press F5 then all works fine, and they don't have to press F5 again to see controls rendering properly.

Is it normal behaviour or there is a workaround?

**.js file**

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();


$(function () {


    $("#uc_DDiscipline select").multiselect({

        header: false,
        multiple: false,
        selectedList: 1,
        minWidth: 265
    });

});

prm.add_endRequest(function () {

    $('.ui-multiselect-menu').each(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $("#uc_DDiscipline select").multiselect({

        header: "-- View All --",
        multiple: false,
        noneSelectedText: "-- View All --",
        selectedList: 1,
        minWidth: 265
    });

});
```

Comment: Could be a dependency problem. In some cases the JS file isn't loaded, but code dependent on it is already ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour. After deployment, the the browser is still caching and using the old .js file. After pressing F5, the current .js is downloaded and everything seems to work again.

What you can do against this, is to add a parameter to the .js filename
For example:

```
/Scripts/MyScrjpt.js?deployedOn=20150223
```

The browser thinks, that a new file is around and has to be downloaded. Therefore you have to change the parameter value each time you deploy your application.

Comment: where do i need to add this parameter "/Scripts/MyScrjpt.js?deployedOn=20150223". Script is in .js file and its being referenced in user control  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/user-find.js"></script>

Comment: Try to add it like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/user-find.js?deployedOn=20150223"></script>

Comment: do i need to do anything with parameter 'deployedOn=20150223' in my .js file?

Comment: No you don't need to do anything with this. You could even add something very short like 'user-find.js?v=1'. The important thing is that you add a GET parameter (using ?) at the end of the filename.